# Matplotlib - what is the best way to draw a straight line between the highs and lows of a stock graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a bunch of data that plots a graph like the black part of the following image (think stock graph). Let's assume this data is all within 1 month. Here, we have 5 high humps, and 5 low humps.

[image]

What is the best way to recognize those high and low humps of the black line, and put another diagonal line over them (green in this case) so that it shows a narrowing?? I'm not asking for an answer in code, just if there is a quick option, because when I look through the [examples on matplotlib,](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) I don't see anything that does this.

Or would I need some other library or something for this???

Comment: How about using `add_artist(lines.Line2D())` if you want to add lines simply?[Adding lines to figures](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/pyplots/fig_x.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-fig-x-py)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but the problem then is that I have to see the graph first before adding the lines, and then insert them on top. In that case, I'd rather just us e a regular image editor. I was looking for something that would be able to recognize the highs / lows without my help, and then add a line on them... It's looking to me like I might need some machine learning or something else. But thank you very much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't take a look at [mlpfinance](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance), although diagonal line (green) you might have to write a custom plot, similar line can be achieved drawing long duration simple moving average.

Edit:

plotting cummax()

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I checked it out, and I really need something that shows a range (between 2 straight diagonal lines).

Comment: if you are using numpy or pandas `cummax()` and `cummin()` might help! (I'm just gussing here haven't tried)  then take unique vaules and plot straight line.